# Discord.js get user by nickname

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm having a hard time figuring out

1. Is is possible to find a user by his or her nickname via the discord.js npm package.
2. How can I query a user by his or her nickname?

i've tried several things but nothing returns the nickname and I can't quite figure out how their documentation works.

So far I haven't been able to tell how to do it.

I've done as so in my code.

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js')
const discordClient = new Client()

discordClient.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return
  if (message.content.startsWith('!gpwarn')) {
    // The command is something like '!gpwarn thomas'.
    // If his nick name is thomas but his username is john it doesn't work.
})
```

Comment: Maybe try to find the members cache for `nickname` equals arguments provided

Comment: I've tried with the `Guild` but doesn't seem to comply. Do you have an example @DarylGill?

Comment: So going by what you have provided, what is your expected input with this command? Tag, nickname & username?

Comment: I need it to work with both nickname and username. So either `thomas` or `john` would return the same answer as it is one and the same person. As his username is `john` that's easy but the nickname `thomas` is harder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's pretty simple. Do this:

```js
const user = client.users.cache.find(user => user.username == "The user's name");
```

---

### Reference:

- [UserManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager)

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't solve my issue. I got the nickname provided by a user in the chat. I have to match it with a username somehow.

Comment: So you want to get the `user` with a `mention`?

Comment: No, no mention.
The user will write something like;
```user1: 50,
user2: 11,
user3: 123```
When my code looks through it I has to check if the name (`user1-3`) matches either a username or a nickname of a person on the server.

Answer (score 0):

To meet your exact requirements you would search the guild members cache for the provided nickname. However, I personally would suggest using either a direct tag or a UserID for this, as multiple people can have the same nickname in the server.

```
const U = message.guild.members.cache.find(E => E.nickname === 'NICKNAME')
```

Getting by Tag:

```
 const U = message.mentions.members.first()
```

Getting by ID:

```
 const U = message.guild.members.cache.find(U => U.id === 'IDHERE')
```

Comment: Thanks but the issue is, that I'm going to provide the bot a list of approx. 150 people with a number at the end. I don't want to tag each and every one.

The `const U = message.guild.members.cache.find(E => E.nickname === 'NICKNAME')` returns undefined for me even though I know that the nickname is on the server.

Comment: Check the argument you are passing as 'NICKNAME' is correct

Answer (score 0):

First you need to **identify the nickname argument**, you can do this by splitting, slicing, and joining `message.content`.

---

Next I recommend you **fetch all of the GuildMembers** from the guild using [GuildMemberManager#fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch), This way you don't run into the error of a member being uncached.

**Handle the promise** using async/await and **use** `Collection#find()` **to return the member**.

```
const { Client } = require('discord.js')
const discordClient = new Client()

discordClient.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return
  if (message.content.startsWith('!gpwarn')) {
    // Returns all of the text after !gpwarn
    const query = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ').toLowerCase()
    const members = await message.guild.members.fetch()
    const memberToWarn = members.find(m => m.nickname.toLowerCase() === query)
    if (!memberToWarn) // No member found error
    console.log(memberToWarn) // [GuildMember]
  }
})
```

Comment: This looks promising but I do get a timeout running `await messages.guild.members.fetch()`.

Comment: Try enabling guild members intent in your developer portal if you haven't already